# Is mongo or sql database always active?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, firebase, backend

I'm just start to learning about backend and database things, I have some confuse that i hope everyone can explain for me

**1. Is backend server always active ( this case is MongoDB )?**
I work with front-end before, and i can always make a network request to that backend server, and example if i make a database with local storage in my computer, is that my computer have to power on everytime to make the request things?

**2. So how we handle that problem?**
We also have serverless database like firebase for example, but for large user base, it will cost a lots, so in my opinions, if want to build large project, we will use other like SQL or Mongo,but i wonder, for individual like me, is that anyway to have that type of server that always can request? As above, if true, so we need to run the computer all the time, or we have another solution that keep backend up all time, like we always can get data and update data to it, even we turn off computer?

Sorry for these question maybe look hilarius to other, but i don't know muc about backend

Comment: Servers have to be active to answer requests. You can host a server in your office, or in a hosting company, but it must always be active if you're using it to serve requests. A `serverless` database does not have servers dedicated to your application. It still has servers, and the load from multiple applications is spread between them.

Comment: The server has to be active as long as you like to use the service. When it is only you who uses it, then you can turn it off when you do not need it.